# Docker hardware virtualization conflicts with virtualbox vms

Tags: docker, virtualbox, virtualization, hyper-v

I am using docker for windows. And also virtualbox to virtualize couple of servers. Getting the conflict about hardware virtualization and data execution and don't know how to solve it! Virtualbox needs hyper-v(I think it is hyper-v) disabled. And docker needs it disabled. So the conflict emerges. How do I get boths to work?

```
Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must be enabled in the BIOS. See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#virtualization-must-be-enabled
```

Comment: Just to be sure. You enabled virtualization in the BIOS configurations?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run Docker Desktop 4.5.1 and Oracle VirtualBox 6.1.32 (including Genymotion 3.2.1) on Windows 10 21H1 64-bit, since VirtualBox supports Hyper-V (be aware the *virtual machines will run very slow* in "turtle mode").

1. You have to enable Windows Hypervisor with `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto` and reboot your PC.
2. Enable experimental Hyper-V support in VirtualBox with executing `VBoxManage setextradata global "VBoxInternal/NEM/UseRing0Runloop" 0` (the tool is in `"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox"`).
   This tool just adds the line `<ExtraDataItem name="VBoxInternal/NEM/UseRing0Runloop" value="0"/>` to your `?:\Users\%USERNAME%\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml`, so you can edit it manually when VirtualBox app isn't running (otherwise the changes will be lost when the app terminates).

Check every VM settings at System => Acceleration: `Default` should be specified as `Paravirtualization Interface`.
Keeping `Default` here lets you easily switch back to the faster acceleration when you execute `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` and reboot (note that Docker will stop working after that).

After that I was able to run virtual Windows 7 x32 and Windows 8.1 x64 as well as Samsung Galaxy S10 (Android 10) on my Windows 10 21H1.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issues...
I disable the Hyper-V in windows [programs and features] but then I can't run virtual machines at least docker works.
after that, when I need my VMs I stop docker and re-enable Hyper-V.

you can use a script to turn off:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

and then this to turn back on

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```